# How to retrieve image stored in firebase storage to my NextJs website?

Tags: firebase, image, web, next.js, firebase-storage

I'm a beginner in NextJs and I'm having trouble fetching an image already stored in firebase storage to my website.

I've tried several solutions and none of them are working.
At this moment the console returns me this error:
"Image is missing required "src" property".

I didn't find much concrete information about this on google. I'm sure it will be useful for a lot of people.
I hope someone can help me, I've been stuck here for over 24 hours..

Here is my code:

`````
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { firebaseConfig } from "@/firebase/firebase";
import { initializeApp } from "@/firebase/firebase";
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"
import styles from "../../styles/collections.module.css"


initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default function Test() {

    const [url, setUrl] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const func = async () => {
            const storage = getStorage();
            const reference = ref(storage, 'collections/amsterdam/bedroom/image10.avif');
            await getDownloadURL(reference).then((x) => {
                setUrl(x);
            })
        }

        func();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={styles.test}>
            <div className={styles.test_container}>
                <h1>Fetching image from firebase to NextJs project.</h1>
                <Image
                    source={{ uri:url }}
                    width={500}
                    height={500}
                    alt=""
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}````
`````

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you need to define the "src" property

```
<Image
  src={url}
  width={500}
  height={500}
  alt=""
/>
```